# Flink Cogroup - value map is not a member of Object

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I try to run the example Scala code of CoGroup function, which is provided in the [Flink website](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/dataset/transformations/#cogroup) , but it throw error "value map is not a member of Object".
Here is my code

```
val iVals: DataSet[(String, Int)] = env.fromCollection(Seq(("a",1),("b",2),("c",3)))
val dVals: DataSet[(String, Int)] = env.fromCollection(Seq(("a",11),("b",22)))

val output = iVals.coGroup(dVals).where(0).equalTo(0) {
  (iVals, dVals, out: Collector[Double]) =>
    val ints = iVals map { _._2 } toSet

    for (dVal <- dVals) {
      for (i <- ints) {
        out.collect(dVal._2 * i)
      }
    }
}

output.print()
```

I don't know what cause the error or is there any library I miss to import? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the type annotations for `iVals` and `dVals`? It seems that Scala is inferring the type `Object`, hence the error. (Why, I don't know).

What I mean is:

```
(iVals: Iterator[(String, Int)], dVals: Iterator[(String, Int)], out: Collector[Double]) =>
```